# Jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheet

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Как мне задать высоту модалки больше стандартной? Так как после параметра в 420.dp высота модалки не увиличивается

```
if(isSheetOpen) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            sheetState = sheetState,
            containerColor = Color(0xFF0D0D0D),
            tonalElevation = 600.dp,
            onDismissRequest = {
                isSheetOpen = false
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(600.dp)


        )
```

[image: Фото модалки сейчас]